# Evaluate transcluded text before compiling template in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a "collapseText" directive in AngularJS. Its function is to display a maximum of "maxLength" characters and a "Read More" option which would then load the rest of the text, if it is too big.

I would like my directive to be able to transclude text, including expressions.

Ideally, I would like it to look as such:

```
<collapse-text max-length="10">This text will be collapsed</collapse-text>
<collapse-text max-length="10">{{foo}}</collapse-text>
```

The template I'm using is:

```
<span>{{lessText}}</span>
<span ng-if="overflow">
    <span ng-if="!readMore" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="toggleReadMore()">...(read more)</span>
    <span ng-if="readMore">{{moreText}}</span>
</span>
```

My directive looks like this:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('myModule')

.directive('collapseText', function($window){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.toggleReadMore = function(){
                $scope.readMore = true;
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            scope.maxLength = attrs.maxLength;
/* 1. Evaluate transcluded element */
/* 2. Check transcluded element's length */
/* 3. Set lessText, moreText, readMore and overflow */
/* 4. Evaluate this directive's template */
            console.log(transclude(scope.$parent, function(compiled){
                scope.lessText = compiled.text().substring(0, scope.maxLength);
                scope.moreText = compiled.text().substring(0, scope.maxLength);
                scope.readMore = false;
                scope.overflow = scope.moreText ? true : false;
                return compiled.text();
            }).text());
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/collapse-text-template.html"
    }
});
```

What is the proper way to go through steps 1-4?
Two symptoms which I see are:

1. **SOLVED**: The ng-if statements are not re-evaluated after the overflow and readMore variables have been updated and, therefore, those text fields never appear in the DOM.

   - I have fixed the ng-if statements not being re-evaluated by changing them to "overflow === true", "readMore === false" and "readMore === true", respectively. I'd still appreciate some clarification as to why it doesn't work simply with . The main issue, regarding transcluded text evaluation, persists.
2. **PENDING**:{{foo}} gets printed as "{{foo}}" and not as "The text that foo contains".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Aletheios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350193/aletheios) suggested, I figured out one way to do it was by implementing a watch on the transcluded text and a manual transclude function which would simply store the raw input in the local scope.
The way it is implemented, it will display the raw input in the "lessText" field, which will later on be processed by the parent who will perform its transclusion. This transclusion will trigger the watch in the collapseText directive.

I can think of some issues which may occur, although I'm not entirely sure of them because I'm quite new to AngularJS:

- If text longer than that displayed by "maxLength" is transcluded and it needs further processing, will it work? Example:

  ```
  <collapse-text max-length="10" {{myLongVariableName.anotherLongVariableName}}</collapse-text>
  ```
- This code does not allow text with any markup at all. Example:

  ```
  <collapse-text max-length="20"><b>I am bold</b></collapse-text>
  ```
- Even if it did allow text with markup, there is the possibility of the markup being broken when split into lessText and moreText.

## The solution

Initial tests point to it working perfectly fine with plaintext and AngularJS expressions.

### use.html

One thing to note here is that I intend to use this code within another directive and therefore `{{parent.foo}}` is also supposed to work.

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MyController">
    <collapse-text max-length="10">This text will be collapsed</collapse-text>
    <collapse-text max-length="10">{{foo}}</collapse-text>
</div>
```

### template.html

```
<span ng-if="readMore === false">{{lessText}}</span>
<span ng-if="overflow === true">
    <span ng-if="readMore === false" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="toggleReadMore()">...(read more)</span>
    <span ng-if="readMore === true">{{moreText}}</span>
</span>
```

### Script

```
angular.module("myModule")
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.foo = 'This text will also be collapsed';
})
.directive('collapseText', function($window){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.readMore = false;
            $scope.toggleReadMore = function(){
                $scope.readMore = true;
            }

            $scope.$watch(
                            function(){
                                return $scope.transcluded;
                            },
                            function(newValue){
                                if($scope.transcluded){
                                    $scope.lessText = $scope.transcluded.text().substring(0, $scope.maxLength);
                                    $scope.moreText = $scope.transcluded.text();
                                    $scope.readMore = false || $scope.readMore; //If it was arleady true, do not collapse it again.
                                    $scope.overflow = $scope.moreText ? true : false;
                                }
                            }
                        );
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            scope.maxLength = attrs.maxLength;
            transclude(scope.$parent, function(transcluded){
                scope.transcluded = transcluded;
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "template.html"
    }
});
```

I would greatly appreciate further feedback regarding the code and "best practices" when implementing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In the directive's `link()` function you'll have to wait until `{{foo}}` has been evaluated and can be used. This can be done by scheduling a new task in the browser's event loop using `$timeout()`. I'm not sure if it's the cleanest solution but at least it works.

Here's your code with `$timeout()` and a few minor improvements:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MyController">
    <collapse-text max-length="10">This text will be collapsed</collapse-text>
    <collapse-text max-length="10">{{foo}}</collapse-text>
</div>
```

**template.html**

```
<span ng-if="!readMore">{{lessText}}</span>
<span ng-if="overflow">
    <span ng-if="!readMore && overflow" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="toggleReadMore()">...(read more)</span>
    <span ng-if="readMore">{{moreText}}</span>
</span>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.foo = 'This text will also be collapsed';
});

angular.module('myModule').directive('collapseText', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.toggleReadMore = function(){
                $scope.readMore = true;
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            var maxLength = +attrs.maxLength;
            var compiled = transclude(scope.$parent);

            $timeout(function(){
                scope.lessText = compiled.text().substring(0, maxLength);
                scope.moreText = compiled.text();
                scope.readMore = false;
                scope.overflow = scope.moreText.length > maxLength;
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "template.html"
    }
});
```

Note that this implementation does not react to updates of `$scope.foo` (i.e. the directive will not see updates and re-render). If you need this, I suggest you pass the content to the directive in an attribute and implement a watcher instead of using transclusion. For example:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('collapseText', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myContent: '=',
            // ...
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.$watch('myContent', function(newValue){
                if (newValue !== undefined) {
                    doSomethingWith(newValue);
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "template.html"
    }
});
```